# Why i am getting type mismatch error when calling macro from vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

When i am calling below macro from vbscript why i am getting type mismatch error

Macro in parameter.xlsm

```
Sub Proc(sParam1 As String, iParam2 As Integer)
MsgBox sParam1 & " is " & iParam2 & " Years Old"
End Sub
```

VB Script code

```
Dim objExcel,objWorkbook

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\ExcelFiles\parameter.xlsm")
sParam1 = Inputbox("Enter the first parameter")
iParam2 = Inputbox("Enter the second parameter")
iParam3= CInt(iParam2)

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

objExcel.Application.Run "parameter.xlsm!Proc",sParam1,iParam3
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring your variables explicitly in the vbscript... I also used a `long` in the workbook code out of habit.

Code inside parameter.xlsm:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Proc(sParam1 As String, iParam2 As Long)
    MsgBox sParam1 & " is " & iParam2 & " Years Old"
End Sub
```

VBScript code:

```
Dim objExcel As Object
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sParam1 As String
Dim iParam2 As Long, iParam3 As Long

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\ExcelFiles\parameter.xlsm")
sParam1 = InputBox("Enter the first parameter")
iParam2 = InputBox("Enter the second parameter")
iParam3 = CInt(iParam2)

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

objExcel.Application.Run "parameter.xlsm!Proc", sParam1, iParam3
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: I think in we cannot dim variables as something in particular in VBS and If we attempt to Dim a variable as anything, it will throw an error. After modifying above script at only this line objExcel.Application.Run "parameter.xlsm!Proc", CStr(sParam1), CInt(iParam3). It worked

Comment: Great point, and a major mistake on my part -- all variables in vbscript are variants. Glad you got this sorted!

Answer (score 1):

In your procedure you are concatenating strings but the second parameter is of type integer. You need to cast to a string first using the CStr() function

```
Sub Proc(sParam1 As String, iParam2 As Integer)
MsgBox sParam1 & " is " & CStr(iParam2) & " Years Old"
End Sub
```

Comment: Pepto,without changing my procedure if i am entering value for sParam1 as "David" and iParam3 as 30 manually i am not getting any error

Comment: Sorry that's all I could think of =( I assume it's the objExcel.Application.Run that's throwing the error?